# jQuery click brings me to top of page. But I want to stay where I am

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple click and show, click and hide button, but when I click it, the page anchors at the top of the page. Is there anyway to prevent this? So that when I click the button, I stay at the same place in the browser?

My code is..

```
$('#reportThis').hide();

$('#flagThis').click(function () {
    $('#reportThis').show("slow");
});
$('#submitFlag').click(function () {
    $('#reportThis').hide("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#reportThis').hide();

$('#flagThis').click(function (evt) {
        $('#reportThis').show("slow");
        evt.preventDefault();
});
$('#submitFlag').click(function (evt) {
        $('#reportThis').hide("slow");
        evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably are binding this clicks to a <a> tag which has a default action. To prevent this you can use another tag like <div> or you can do this:

```
$('#flagThis').click(function (event) {
        $('#reportThis').show("slow");
        event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try returning `false` in the `click` function:

```
$('#reportThis').hide();

$('#flagThis').click(function () {
        $('#reportThis').show("slow");
        return false;
});
$('#submitFlag').click(function () {
        $('#reportThis').hide("slow");
        return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the hyperlinks to point to a non-existent anchor, like this:

```
<a href="#IDontExist" id="flagThis">Flag</a>
```

Or, make your handlers return `false`, like this:

```
$('#reportThis').hide();

$('#flagThis').click(function () {
    $('#reportThis').show("slow");
    return false;
});
$('#submitFlag').click(function () {
    $('#reportThis').hide("slow");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `<button>` element don't forget to set the type attribute.

```
<button type="button">My Button</button>
```

Some browsers default to submit which will bring you back to the beginning of your page.

It's where I was going wrong anyway and saw nothing here about it so thought I'd share my two cents for future readers.