# <a> tag brings me to top of page with angularjs. But I want to stay at the same place

Tags: angularjs

I have a click button. I am trying with angularjs. The page anchors at the top of the page, when I click it. How do I to stay at the same place in the browser when I click it?

```
<a href="#" ng-click="myFunction()">
   {{_actions.refresh}}
</a>
```

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976753/jquery-click-brings-me-to-top-of-page-but-i-want-to-stay-where-i-am). But with jQuery solution described there. I would like to find a solution with angularjs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<a ng-click="myFunction()">
   {{_actions.refresh}}
</a>
```

Just remove `href` completely.

Answer (score 0):

So, the "right" way to do it would be something like this:

```
<a name="myFunction"></a>
<a href="#myFunction" ng-click="myFunction()">
   {{_actions.refresh}}
</a>
```

That way you could have some extra functionality in terms of someone sending that link, or someone visiting the page without JavaScript (have you thought about that experience yet?).

I obviously don't know your applications, but putting a name tag in there might be a helpful thing on several levels.